# Poisson likelihood for count data - comparing (scaled) model and observations

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have two 2D histograms - one has observed counts and the other has predicted counts from a model. I am comparing both of them using a Poisson likelihood while varying the parameters of the model.

What is important to me is the shape of the 2D distributions and not that the total counts of the model Nmod be equal to the total counts of the observations Nobs.

My question is how should I scale the model to handle this correctly? Can I just normalise my model by dividing all counts in the model 2D histogram by Nmod and then multiplying by Nobs?

EDIT: I am using MCMC to find the optimum parameters for my model, so trying to find the maximum likelihood. The data are the equivalent of a monochromatic image, where a 2D histogram has an integer representing the counts in each pixel. Using a simulation, with a handful of variable parameters, I am able to produce a modelled image. The pixels in the model image contain non-integer values. As I said above it is the details in the image and not the brightness that I am interested in.

EDIT2: I build the histogram out of observed data. Imagine data consisting of x,y coordinates and I build a 2d histogram with a binning in x and y that I have chosen.

Comment: This sounds odd. Are you saying that you just want the histograms shape to be similar? Not the model to be accurate (your second sentence on total counts)?

Comment: Yes, I would like to find the model that results in the histogram shapes being similar, even if there is a global shift between the two.

Comment: This sounds analogous to saying that you want to choose the correct residual distribution. Which is a good goal, but one that is hard to help you with unless we understand more about your data and model.

Comment: I have edited my initial post to try to provide more details.

Comment: I don't understand. You say "The data are the equivalent of a monochromatic image, where a 2D histogram has an integer representing the counts in each pixel". Is the data the HISTOGRAM, or is the data the PIXELS and then you built an histogram with counts of data from it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being very clear. I build the histogram out of observed data. Imagine data consisting of x,y coordinates and I build a 2d histogram with a binning in x and y that I have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "comparing". If you just want to look at both curves visually, then what you said works. Alternatively you could normalise both independently in the same way as a probability mass function, i.e. compute $\sum c_i = A$ where $c_i$ are counts, and then divide each $c_i$ by A, and do this process independently for each set.

If by "comparing" you mean something else you're gonna have to be more specific.

Comment: By comparing I mean obtain a quantitative measure of their similarity. I thought of  using a Poisson likelihood but was usure if scaling the model invalidated its use.

Comment: How are you obtaining the model? Is it a maximum likelihood fit? Can you give us more specifics?

Comment: I have edited my initial post to try to provide more details.